# How to remove duplicates in knockout js dropdown list

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying the bind a dropdown list in knockout js, but in my data there are some duplicates is it possible remove these duplicates while binding to the dropdown list?

Here is how i bind the data

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
               optionsText: function(item) {
                   return item.countryName + ' (pop: ' + item.countryPopulation + ')'
               },
               value: selectedCountry,
               optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

var Country = function(name, population) {
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = population;
};
```

and my viewmodel is as below

```
var AppViewModel = function() {
this.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
        new Country("UK", 65000000),
        new Country("USA", 320000000),
        new Country("Sweden", 29000000),
     new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
    ]);
    this.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
};
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Here is the js fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/PV7yD/

Thanks,

Praveen.

Comment: If it's not important to do this *while* binding I'd suggest making a second computed observable that only has the distinct available countries. In that case your question would become a duplicate of [this one on removing dupes from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2218999/419956).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Underscore's `_.uniq` function in a computed observable, with an iterator that serializes each item to JSON for full comparison. Like this:

```
this.displayedCountries = ko.computed( function () {
    return _.uniq( this.availableCountries(), false, ko.toJSON );
}, this );
```

And you could replace `ko.toJSON` with a function that only returns the `countryName` property  of a country if that's enough to determine uniqueness (which it probably is in this case).

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PV7yD/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues function to get distinct values or you can use filter.

```
 self.uniqueCountries = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var seen = [];
    return self.availableCountries().filter(function (n) {
        return seen.indexOf(n.countryName+'-'+n.countryPopulation) == -1 && seen.push(n.countryName+'-'+n.countryPopulation);
    });
}, self);
```

view:-

```
 <select data-bind="options: uniqueCountries,
               optionsText: function(item) {
                   return item.countryName + ' (pop: ' + item.countryPopulation + ')'
               },
               value: selectedCountry,
               optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

For more info:-

1. [**see this**](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)
2. [**Another Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437849/knockout-arraygetdistinctvalues-of-objects)

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PV7yD/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the links akhlesh. Is it possible filter based on countryName + Population as unique key instead of just country?

Comment: Do you mean to say that countryName+Population has uniqueness?  If so, then the uniqueness of countryName alone is sufficient.  Or did you mean can you _sort_ by Population once you've narrowed the country list to unique values?